# pandas insert multiple columns starting at index

Tags: python, pandas, insert, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe like this. I need to insert several empty columns starting at index 1. The code below works, but I am trying to find a way to combine the 4 lines like this:

`df.insert(loc=n, column='x', value='')`

Into one line, does anyone know a way to do this? Thanks

```
d = {'one' : pd.Series([10, 20, 30, 40],), 
      'two' : pd.Series([10, 20, 30, 40],),
      'three' : pd.Series([10, 20, 30, 40],)}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df.insert(loc=1, column='A', value='')
df.insert(loc=2, column='B', value='')
df.insert(loc=3, column='C', value='')
df.insert(loc=4, column='D', value='')

df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with new helper `DataFrame`:

```
i = 1
df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :i], 
                pd.DataFrame('', columns=['A','B','C','D'], index=df.index), 
                df.iloc[:, i:]], axis=1)
print (df)
   one A B C D  two  three
0   10           10     10
1   20           20     20
2   30           30     30
3   40           40     40
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this single line:

```
df.loc[index,'columns'] = value
```